# How to render between two elements in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

Here's the original HTML:

```html
<div class="chat">
    <div class="uploadArea">
        ...
    </div>
    <section class="title">
        ...
    </section>
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to render a component between the `title` and the `content`. How can I do that?

```js
ReactDOM.render(Component, document.getElementsByClassName("chat")[0]);
```

wouldn't really work, right?

Comment: You need to place a DOM node in between the title and content `div`s and render the React Tree in that. You can also create the dom node programmatically with javascript, and render inside of that.

Comment: Covered step-by-step in the documentation: [Add React to a Website](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an element which you can use as the container for you react application.
Insert the created element in the position you want, like in this example [`after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after) the `.title` element.

Then use the created element in the `ReactDOM.render` call.

#### React 17 and below:

```
const reactContainer = document.createElement('div');
const target = document.querySelector('.chat .title');

target.after(reactContainer);

ReactDOM.render(Component, reactContainer);
```

#### React 18 and above:

```
const reactContainer = document.createElement('div');
const target = document.querySelector('.chat .title');

target.after(reactContainer);

const root = createRoot(reactContainer);
root.render(Component);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that [React 18 has changed the root API](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-client-rendering-apis) so it would be `const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(reactContainer); root.render(Component);`

Comment: @pilchard good one, I've added an additional example based on your link.